# Beginning and pausing SVG animations on hover

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I would like to animate the gears on the following SVG when the user hovers over it. That is, when the mouse enters, both gears begin rotating where they left off. When the mouse leaves, the gears stop in whatever position they're in. If possible I would like the animation to begin and end using an ease-in/out function. How can this be done using SVG animations?

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/awmtB)**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 256 256">

    <path d="M249.363 80.921l-6.402-15.451c-1.769-4.267-6.659-6.292-10.927-4.528l-9.032 3.7 c-8.043-12.801-18.893-23.646-31.692-31.689l3.744-9.032c1.768-4.266-0.258-9.162-4.528-10.926l-15.45-6.402 c-4.264-1.764-9.16 0.261-10.923 4.523l-3.744 9.032c-14.458-3.293-29.542-3.478-44.817 0l-3.74-9.028 c-1.768-4.267-6.659-6.292-10.926-4.528l-15.451 6.402c-4.267 1.768-6.296 6.656-4.528 10.926l3.744 9 C71.893 41 61 51.9 53 64.687l-9.032-3.744c-4.263-1.764-9.158 0.261-10.927 4.528l-6.398 15.5 c-1.768 4.3 0.3 9.2 4.5 10.926l9.028 3.74c-3.349 14.666-3.435 29.8 0 44.816l-9.028 3.7 c-4.271 1.768-6.296 6.664-4.528 10.926l6.398 15.451c1.772 4.3 6.7 6.3 10.9 4.524l9.032-3.741 c8.044 12.8 18.9 23.6 31.7 31.693l-3.74 9.032c-1.768 4.3 0.3 9.2 4.5 10.927l15.451 6.4 c4.267 1.8 9.158-0.257 10.926-4.528l3.74-9.028c14.613 3.3 29.7 3.4 44.8 0l3.739 9 c1.768 4.3 6.7 6.3 10.9 4.528l15.45-6.402c4.267-1.768 6.292-6.663 4.524-10.927l-3.744-9.032 c12.8-8.048 23.649-18.896 31.692-31.693l9.032 3.741c4.268 1.8 9.158-0.254 10.927-4.524l6.398-15.451 c1.768-4.262-0.257-9.162-4.524-10.922l-9.032-3.739c3.328-14.583 3.458-29.682 0-44.825l9.032-3.74 C249.103 90.1 251.1 85.2 249.4 80.921z M138 176.536c-32.278 0-58.537-26.259-58.537-58.536 c0-32.281 26.259-58.536 58.537-58.536c32.276 0 58.5 26.3 58.5 58.536C196.535 150.3 170.3 176.5 138 176.536z">
        <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform"
            repeatCount="indefinite"
            type="rotate"
            from="00 138 118"
            to="+360 138 118"
            begin="0s" dur="30s"/>
    </path>

    <path d="M57.552 217.745l-2.16 0.895c0.811 3.6 0.8 7.2 0 10.721l2.16 0.895c1.021 0.4 1.5 1.6 1.1 2.612l-1.53 3.7 c-0.423 1.021-1.593 1.506-2.613 1.082l-2.16-0.895c-1.924 3.061-4.519 5.655-7.58 7.58l0.895 2.2 c0.423 1.02-0.062 2.19-1.082 2.613l-3.695 1.531c-1.021 0.422-2.191-0.063-2.614-1.083l-0.895-2.16 c-3.508 0.801-7.12 0.821-10.719 0l-0.895 2.159c-0.423 1.021-1.593 1.506-2.613 1.083l-3.695-1.53 c-1.021-0.423-1.505-1.594-1.082-2.613l0.895-2.16c-3.062-1.924-5.656-4.519-7.581-7.58l-2.16 0.9 c-1.021 0.424-2.189-0.061-2.613-1.082l-1.53-3.695c-0.423-1.02 0.062-2.19 1.083-2.613l2.159-0.895 c-0.801-3.507-0.821-7.121 0-10.719l-2.159-0.895c-1.021-0.424-1.506-1.594-1.083-2.613l1.53-3.696 c0.423-1.021 1.594-1.505 2.613-1.083l2.161 0.896c1.924-3.062 4.519-5.655 7.58-7.579l-0.896-2.16 c-0.423-1.021 0.063-2.19 1.083-2.613l3.695-1.531c1.021-0.422 2.2 0.1 2.6 1.083l0.895 2.159c3.427-0.78 7.035-0.839 10.7 0 l0.895-2.16c0.422-1.02 1.593-1.504 2.612-1.082l3.695 1.531c1.021 0.4 1.5 1.6 1.1 2.613l-0.895 2.2 c3.061 1.9 5.7 4.5 7.6 7.579l2.161-0.896c1.021-0.422 2.2 0.1 2.6 1.083l1.531 3.7 C59.057 216.2 58.6 217.3 57.6 217.745z M46 224c0-7.721-6.28-14-14-14s-14 6.279-14 14c0 7.7 6.3 14 14 14 S46 231.7 46 224z">
        <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform"
            repeatCount="indefinite"
            type="rotate"
            from="00 32 224"
            to="-360 32 224"
            begin="0s" dur="20s"/>
    </path>

</svg>
```

Comment: restart an aminaton where it left off is not possible in SMIL without javascript to stop/restart the timeline.

Comment: Have you considered using css animations or transitions instead?

Comment: @ErikDahlström: If there's a way to use CSS I'd like to know. As long as I can do it without Javascript, although I will settle for JS if I have to.

Comment: Ur Codepen causes my pc to crash ;(

Comment: None answered how to ease-in-out

Answer (score 13):

Assuming the cogs have id `big` and `little`, here's a way to do this using css animations:

```
#big {
    transform-origin: 138px 118px;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-name: rotateBig;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
#little {
    transform-origin: 32px 224px;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-name: rotateLittle;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
#big:hover, #little:hover {
    animation-play-state: running;
}
@keyframes rotateBig {
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotateLittle {
    to {
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

See [live example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/css/animations/hover-transform.svg). This animates each of the gears individually when hovered.

For something that animates both gears when the whole svg is hovered:

```
#big {
    transform-origin: 138px 118px;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-name: rotateBig;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#little {
    transform-origin: 32px 224px;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-name: rotateLittle;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;        
}
svg > * { 
    animation-play-state: paused; 
}
svg:hover > * {
    animation-play-state: running;
}
@keyframes rotateBig {
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotateLittle {
    to {
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

See [live example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/css/animations/hover-root-transform.svg). The only difference is what selectors set `animation-play-state`.

You may have to resort to using css vendor prefixes to get this to be more compatible, but I've provided it in the cleanest form I could. The fiddle works fine in Opera 25, Chrome 38 and Firefox Nightly 34 at least.

A slight downside with the solution here is that the begin and end isn't using ease-in-out, this is because that makes the repetitions visible. If anyone has a clever idea for how to fix that without using script I'm all ears.

Comment: Looks like a good solution but how can I start / stop the animation when my mouse enters the SVG (as opposed to each individual gear)?

Comment: +1. CSS3 solution more streamlined vs script. Is "-webkit-animation-timing-xxxx" still in fashion these days? @Erik: Is there any way to make "tick" like the second hand of the clock with CSS animation?

Answer (score 7):

You are **almost** there. Add this tweaks:

- Add `id="gear1"` to first `<path...>`
- Add `id="gear2"` to second `<path...>`
- End both `<path...` with this `onmouseover=runGears(); onmouseout=stopGears(); >`
- remove `<animate .....>` from both `<path....>`

On the JS magic to rotate the gears, use this code:

```
var animateGears ; // event handler
var angle = 0; // rotation of angle

var gear1 = document.getElementById("gear1");
var gear2 = document.getElementById("gear2");

function runGears() {
animateGears = setInterval( function () {
        angle += 5;
        if (angle == 360 ) { angle = 0 } ; // 360 == 0 degrees

        gear1.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + angle + " 138 118)");
        gear2.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + angle + " 32 224)");
    }, 100);
}

function stopGears() {
    clearInterval(animateGears);
}
```

Note: play around with the Timeout of 100ms and Angle of +5 to make it look smoother.

**Update**: The other JS coding that *may* work for you (without removing the `<animate....`):-

```
var svgDoc =  document.getElementsByTagName('svg');

svgdoc[0].pauseAnimations(); // pause animation at load time

function runGears() {
 svgDoc[0].unpauseAnimations(); // resumes ALL animations
}
function stopGears() {
 svgDoc[0].pauseAnimations(); // pause ALL animations
}
```

Comment: If mouse is inside gears (white space) it stops, you can `<g>`roup each gear with a white circle and use onmouseover & onmouseup on this grouping. Try timeout of 50 and angle of +3, looks smoother. Have fun with code!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using JavaScript but instead use SVG animations or CSS?

Comment: @Dave: I tried adding `fill="freeze" begin="group.mouseover" dur="3s" end="group.mouseout"` to your sample code, but the animation restarts on mouse over, instead of continuing from where it stopped. No combination of `restart`, `additive` or `accumulate` worked for me. I'm not completely convinced, but I'm afraid you might need JavaScript.

Comment: @AlvinK. Instead of `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, consider using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: @Dave: Check this [SVG example](http://svg-whiz.com/svg/PausePlay.svg), uses pauseAnimations() and unpauseAnimations(). Caveat: it pauses ALL animations.