# How to stop the levitate animation when it hovers

Tags: css, animation, sass, hover, transition

Is there a way to stop the levitate animation on hover?

```
:hover
```

Here is a link which shows the animation:

https://codepen.io/youbiteme/pen/RprPrN

Comment: im looking for an effect stops when it hovers, ive tried this one but its way too quik and fast

&:hover{ animation: paused; }

is there any way that would be a great help thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beginning and pausing SVG animations on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150865/beginning-and-pausing-svg-animations-on-hover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an animation pause to your svg hover

```css
.svg:hover .shaddow,
.svg:hover .right-movment,
.svg:hover .left-movment,
.svg:hover .leon
{
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
     animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

[Updated Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmydoL)

Answer (score 0):

```
.leon:hover {
    animation: none;
}
```

Might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for levitate:

```
.svg:hover .leon {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-play-state: paused;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

For all:

```
.svg:hover .leon,
.svg:hover .right-movment, .svg:hover .left-movment, .svg:hover  .shaddow {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-play-state: paused;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```