# How to stop the animation and freeze the image when pressing the `Stop` button

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

I created a layout of the working planetary gear.

When you click on the `Stop` button, the animation of the rotation of the gears should stop and the image “freeze”.

But in reality the image returns to its original state. This can be seen on the yellow markers on the gears.

Below is the code I’ve made at the moment:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
  <title>animation planetary mechanism</title>
  <defs>
    <marker id="MarkerArrow" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="2" refY="5" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="14" height="10" rx="2" fill="#22211D" />
    </marker>
    <line id="line1" x1="150" y1="100" x2="60" y2="100" style=" fill:none;
                 marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow);
                 marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow);
               stroke:#22211D; stroke-width:6; ">
    </line>
    <marker id="MarkerArrow-s" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="3" refY="1.7" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="7" height="3.5" rx="2" fill="#22211D" />
    </marker>
    <line id="line-s" x1="175" y1="100" x2="202" y2="100" style=" fill:none;
             marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow-s1);
             marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow-s);
           stroke:#22211D; stroke-width:2; ">

    </line>
    <linearGradient id="vertical" x2="0%" y2="100%" spreadMethod="pad">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="powderblue" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="lightgreen" />
    </linearGradient>

  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#vertical)" />
  <g transform="translate(90,50)">

    <g id="wheel">
      <g>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100" begin="gO1.click" end="stop1.click" dur="14s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(0 100 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(120 100 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(240 100 100)" />


        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="15" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 15px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 6;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />
      </g>
    </g>

    <g id="col-small">

      <g>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 188 100" to="-360 188 100" begin="gO1.click" end="stop1.click" dur="3.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(0 188 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(120 188 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(240 188 100)" />

        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="8" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="18" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 7px;" />
        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="24" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="206" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />

      </g>
    </g>
    
    <g id="planetar">
      <g>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 100 100" to="-360 100 100" begin="gO1.click" end="stop1.click" dur="28s" repeatCount="indefinite" />

        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="116" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="124" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 12px;" />
        <circle cx="224" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />
      </g>
    </g>

    <g>
      <use xlink:href="#col-small" transform="rotate(240 100 100)" />
      <use xlink:href="#col-small" transform="rotate(120 100 100)" />
    </g>

    <g transform="translate(-10,160)">
      <g id="gO1">
        <rect x="45" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="#0080B8" stroke="dodgerblue" />
        <text x="62" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">GO</text>
      </g>
      <g id="stop1">
        <rect x="110" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="crimson" stroke="red" />
        <text x="120" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">STOP</text>
      </g>
    </g>

  </g>
</svg>
```

**Question:**

How to make it so that when you click the `Stop` button the image stops in the current state and the next time you press the `GO` button, the animation does not start from the beginning, but from the locked state.

I could not do it. I will be grateful for any solution.

Comment: You can find a CSS solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25156807/4254681) But need to change animation from SMIL style to CSS style

Comment: @Duannx Thank you for the useful link. I tried this before, but it didn’t work. Please publish your decision

Comment: This is what I found in [Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5: Vector Graphics for Web Design](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B076HZ31YZ?pf_rd_p=1581d9f4-062f-453c-b69e-0f3e00ba2652&pf_rd_r=ZYFEX0WHVM0BT73TVHHG): Speaking of limitations of SMIL animations: "You cannot easily **pause**  individual animation effects in process". My interpretation: you'll need javascript to deal with it.

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you, I have this wonderful book that I read. I hope to get your great JS solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have made some changes in the snippet. Please have a look and let me know if this is what you want.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" onload='Init(evt)' id = "SVGRoot">
  <title>animation planetary mechanism</title>
  <defs>
    <marker id="MarkerArrow" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="2" refY="5" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="14" height="10" rx="2" fill="#22211D" />
    </marker>
    <line id="line1" x1="150" y1="100" x2="60" y2="100" style=" fill:none;
     marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow);
     marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow);
      stroke:#22211D; stroke-width:6; ">
    </line>
    <marker id="MarkerArrow-s" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="3" refY="1.7" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="7" height="3.5" rx="2" fill="#22211D" />
    </marker>
    <line id="line-s" x1="175" y1="100" x2="202" y2="100" style=" fill:none;
    marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow-s1);
    marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow-s);
     stroke:#22211D; stroke-width:2; ">

    </line>
    <linearGradient id="vertical" x2="0%" y2="100%" spreadMethod="pad">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="powderblue" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="lightgreen" />
    </linearGradient>

  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#vertical)" />
  <g transform="translate(90,50)">

    <g id="wheel">
      <g>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100" dur="14s" id = "innerCircle" begin="click" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(0 100 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(120 100 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(240 100 100)" />


        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="15" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 15px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 6;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />
      </g>
    </g>

    <g id="col-small">

      <g>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 188 100" to="-360 188 100" id = "smallerCircle" begin="click"  dur="3.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(0 188 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(120 188 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(240 188 100)" />

        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="8" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="18" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 7px;" />
        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="24" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="206" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />

      </g>
    </g>
    
    <g id="planetar">
      <g>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 100 100" to="-360 100 100" id = "outerCircle" begin="click" dur="28s" repeatCount="indefinite" />

        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="116" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="124" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 12px;" />
        <circle cx="224" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />
      </g>
    </g>

    <g>
      <use xlink:href="#col-small" transform="rotate(240 100 100)" />
      <use xlink:href="#col-small" transform="rotate(120 100 100)" />
    </g>

    <g transform="translate(-10,160)">
      <g id="gO1" onclick='Play()'>
        <rect x="45" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="#0080B8" stroke="dodgerblue" />
        <text x="62" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">GO</text>
      </g>
      <g id="stop1" onclick='Pause()'>
        <rect x="110" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="crimson" stroke="red" />
        <text x="120" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">STOP</text>
      </g>
    </g>

  </g>
</svg>
<script>
  var SVGDocument = null;
  var SVGRoot = null;
  var pauseButton = null;
  var playButton = null;
  var innerCircle = null;
  var outerCircle = null;
  var smallerCircle = null;

  function Init(evt)
  {  
     SVGDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
     SVGRoot = SVGDocument.getElementById('SVGRoot')

     pauseButton = SVGDocument.getElementById('stop1');
     playButton = SVGDocument.getElementById('gO1');
     innerCircle = SVGDocument.getElementById('innerCircle');;
     outerCircle = SVGDocument.getElementById('outerCircle');;
     smallerCircle = SVGDocument.getElementById('smallerCircle');;
  };

  function Pause()
  {  
     SVGRoot.pauseAnimations();
  };

  function Play()
  {
     if(SVGRoot.animationsPaused()){
        SVGRoot.unpauseAnimations();
     }
     else{
         innerCircle.beginElement();
         outerCircle.beginElement();
         smallerCircle.beginElement();
     }
  };

   </script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the terms of the decision were: "How to make it so that when you click the `Stop` button the image stops in the current state and the next time you press the `GO` button, the animation does not start from the beginning, but from the locked state "

Comment: At first glance, everything is fine and I like it. I will study your decision

Comment: better add some explanation instead of simply saying *I have edited ..* so we can have a clear idea how it works and probably link to some useful ressources

Comment: @Kumar Aman Thank you. Your decision suited me more than others. So it completely answers my question. Please add comments explaining the code.

Comment: Great demo. Had no idea that there is such a function as `animationsPaused` or unpauseAnimations()

Answer (score 6):

Here is a trick/hack using CSS. The idea is to rely on transition to have the rotation then you play with the duration to create the illusion of *freezing*. By setting a big value you make the transition very very slow thus it will be stopped for us.

You have to adjust the value of transtion/rotation for each wheel to have the speed you want. You also need to make the values bigger enough so the user never reach the end of the transition.

```js
$('#gO1').click(function() {
    $('#wheel,#col-small,#planetar').addClass('rotate').removeClass('rotate-1');
})

$('#stop1').click(function() {
    $('#wheel,#col-small,#planetar').addClass('rotate-1').removeClass('rotate');
})
```

```css
#wheel,
#col-small,
#planetar{
  transform-box:fill-box;
  transform-origin:center;
}
#wheel.rotate{
  transform:rotate(36000deg);
  transition:1400s linear;
}
#planetar.rotate {
  transform:rotate(-36000deg);
  transition:2800s linear;
}
#col-small.rotate {
  transform:rotate(-36000deg);
  transition:350s linear;
}

#wheel.rotate-1{
  transform:rotate(36001deg); /*we need a slight change to re-trigger the transition*/
  transition:140000s linear;
}
#planetar.rotate-1 {
  transform:rotate(-36001deg);
  transition:280000s linear;
}
#col-small.rotate-1 {
 transform:rotate(-36001deg);
  transition:35000s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
  <title>animation planetary mechanism</title>
  <defs>
    <marker id="MarkerArrow" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="2" refY="5" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="14" height="10" rx="2" fill="#22211D" />
    </marker>
    <line id="line1" x1="150" y1="100" x2="60" y2="100" style=" fill:none;
     marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow);
     marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow);
      stroke:#22211D; stroke-width:6; ">
    </line>
    <marker id="MarkerArrow-s" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="3" refY="1.7" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="7" height="3.5" rx="2" fill="#22211D" />
    </marker>
    <line id="line-s" x1="175" y1="100" x2="202" y2="100" style=" fill:none;
    marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow-s1);
    marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow-s);
     stroke:#22211D; stroke-width:2; ">

    </line>
    <linearGradient id="vertical" x2="0%" y2="100%" spreadMethod="pad">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="powderblue" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="lightgreen" />
    </linearGradient>

  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#vertical)" />
  <g transform="translate(90,50)">

    <g id="wheel">
      <g>
       <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(0 100 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(120 100 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(240 100 100)" />

        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="15" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 15px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 6;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />
      </g>
    </g>

    <g id="col-small">

      <g>
       <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(0 188 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(120 188 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(240 188 100)" />

        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="8" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="18" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 7px;" />
        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="24" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="206" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />

      </g>
    </g>
    
    <g id="planetar">
      <g>
       
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="116" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="124" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 12px;" />
        <circle cx="224" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />
      </g>
    </g>

    <g>
      <use xlink:href="#col-small" transform="rotate(240 100 100)" />
      <use xlink:href="#col-small" transform="rotate(120 100 100)" />
    </g>

    <g transform="translate(-10,160)">
      <g id="gO1">
        <rect x="45" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="#0080B8" stroke="dodgerblue" />
        <text x="62" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">GO</text>
      </g>
      <g id="stop1">
        <rect x="110" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="crimson" stroke="red" />
        <text x="120" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">STOP</text>
      </g>
    </g>

  </g>
</svg>
```

**UPDATE**

The above one seems to work fine only on chrome so here another one where I had to duplicate the code of the small wheel so it works fine on Firefox too:

```js
$('#gO1').click(function() {
    $('#wheel,.col-small g,#planetar').addClass('rotate').removeClass('rotate-1');
})

$('#stop1').click(function() {
    $('#wheel,.col-small g,#planetar').addClass('rotate-1').removeClass('rotate');
})
```

```css
#wheel,
.col-small g,
#planetar{
  transform-box:fill-box;
  transform-origin:center;
}
#wheel.rotate{
  transform:rotate(36000deg); /*360 x 100*/
  transition:1400s linear; /*14s x 100*/
}
#planetar.rotate {
  transform:rotate(-36000deg);
  transition:2800s linear;
}
.col-small g.rotate {
  transform:rotate(-36000deg);
  transition:350s linear;
}

#wheel.rotate-1{
  transform:rotate(36001deg); /*we need a slight change to re-trigger the transition*/
  transition:140000s linear; /*14s x 100 x 100*/
}
#planetar.rotate-1 {
  transform:rotate(-36001deg);
  transition:280000s linear;
}
.col-small g.rotate-1 {
 transform:rotate(-36001deg);
  transition:35000s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
  <title>animation planetary mechanism</title>
  <defs>
    <marker id="MarkerArrow" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="2" refY="5" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="14" height="10" rx="2" fill="#22211D" />
    </marker>
    <line id="line1" x1="150" y1="100" x2="60" y2="100" style=" fill:none;
     marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow);
     marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow);
      stroke:#22211D; stroke-width:6; ">
    </line>
    <marker id="MarkerArrow-s" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="3" refY="1.7" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="7" height="3.5" rx="2" fill="#22211D" />
    </marker>
    <line id="line-s" x1="175" y1="100" x2="202" y2="100" style=" fill:none;
    marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow-s1);
    marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow-s);
     stroke:#22211D; stroke-width:2; ">

    </line>
    <linearGradient id="vertical" x2="0%" y2="100%" spreadMethod="pad">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="powderblue" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="lightgreen" />
    </linearGradient>

  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#vertical)" />
  <g transform="translate(90,50)">

    <g id="wheel">
      <g>
       <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(0 100 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(120 100 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(240 100 100)" />

        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="15" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 15px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 6;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />
      </g>
    </g>

    <g class="col-small">

      <g>
       <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(0 188 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(120 188 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(240 188 100)" />

        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="8" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="18" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 7px;" />
        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="24" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="206" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />

      </g>
    </g>
    
    <g id="planetar">
      <g>
       
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="116" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="124" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 12px;" />
        <circle cx="224" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />
      </g>
    </g>

    <g class="col-small" transform="rotate(240 100 100)">
      <g>
       <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(0 188 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(120 188 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(240 188 100)" />

        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="8" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="18" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 7px;" />
        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="24" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="206" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />

      </g>
     </g>
     <g class="col-small" transform="rotate(120 100 100)">
      <g>
       <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(0 188 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(120 188 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(240 188 100)" />

        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="8" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="18" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 7px;" />
        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="24" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="206" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />

      </g>
     </g>
  
    <g transform="translate(-10,160)">
      <g id="gO1">
        <rect x="45" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="#0080B8" stroke="dodgerblue" />
        <text x="62" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">GO</text>
      </g>
      <g id="stop1">
        <rect x="110" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="crimson" stroke="red" />
        <text x="120" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">STOP</text>
      </g>
    </g>

  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Good answer, but 2 of the gears in your snippet do not rotate

Comment: @souzan Firefox I suppose? .. always forget to test there, it's fine on Chrome

Comment: Ok. Yes I'm on Firefox.

Comment: @Temani Afif  Thank you for the interesting decision (+) But there are two points that do not suit me: 1. The appearance of the gears is broken. 2. Synchronism of rotation of the small and large gear wheels is broken.

Comment: @Alexandr_T yes I didn't spend a lot of time to fix the synchronization but it's only a matter of adjust, you need to find the correct value to use with the transtion and rotation to increase/decrease the speed of each rotation and obtain the needed effect (will edit later if I find some times). But how the appearance is broken?

Comment: @Alexandr_T it's fixed. I was hypnotized by the rotation and didn't even notice this :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif Checked in Firefox and Chrome small gears stop spinning after 100s. You can certainly increase this parameter `transition: 100s linear`; But the gears will still stop after all? Probably better to use another solution.JS?

Comment: @Alexandr_T yes this is the limation of this solution ... you can increase it by making it 1000s (x10) and you do the same for rotation (x10) too. We can suppose that a user will not stay for hours on the site, so if for example we make sure the transtion will at least last 1h then it should be fine. We can of course make this more accurate by using some JS to adjust the values but I tried to keep it as simple as possible even with some limitation.

Comment: @Alexandr_T check the update, I have corrected the sync .. as you will notice, I picked the value you used in your animation and I did a x100 for the main transtion then I added another x100 for the stop ... you increase the multiplication more so it last more (simply do it the same for both rotation and delay to keep the same speed)

Comment: @Alexandr_T there is no issue, you have to select one solution that is the best for you and I am fine if it's not mine ;) the purpose of SO is to have different answers providing different method for future reader and all of them will get reward later with upvotes if they are good (so please don't serial upvote me instead)

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution, very similar to the @Duannx solution. However, when it comes to cogs I like to see them fitting. (no overlapping teeth). So what I've made was trying to recalculate the size of the teeth. I hope you will like it.

**The animation starts and begins on clicking the svg canvas**

```js
c1r = 140;//the radius of the _c1 circle
c1perim = 2*Math.PI * c1r;// the perimeter of the _c1 circle

let sda = c1perim / 120;//sda = value for stroke-dasharray
// a css variable used to set the value for stroke-dasharray
cogs.style.setProperty("--foo", sda);
// the perimeter of _c2. This is the smaller circle used for the 3 identical cogs
c2perim = c1perim / Math.PI;
c2r = c1r/4; //the radius of the c2 circle
// the value  of the cx attribute of the _c2
c2cx = 150 + c1r - c2r;// 150 = center.x of the cogs
//the radius of the 3-rd circle, the one in the middle
c3r = c1r - c2r*2


// setting attributes
c1.setAttributeNS(null,"r",(c1r + sda));
_c1.setAttributeNS(null,"r",c1r);


_c2.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",c2cx);
c2.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",c2cx);
_c2.setAttributeNS(null,"r",c2r);
c2.setAttributeNS(null,"r",(c2r-sda));
g2.style.transformOrigin=`${c2cx}px 150px`;

_c3.setAttributeNS(null,"r",c3r);
c3.setAttributeNS(null,"r",(c3r-sda));


//event listener to toggle the class animated of the svg element
cogs.addEventListener("click",()=>{cogs.classList.toggle("animated")})
```

```css
svg {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
circle {
  
  stroke-width: var(--foo);
  fill: none;
}

g {
  transform-origin: 150px 150px;
  animation: rotate 80s linear infinite;
  stroke: black;
}

.animated g{animation-play-state: paused;}
#g2 {
  animation-duration:20s;
  stroke:#444;
}
#g3 {
  animation-duration:40s;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

[id ^="_"] {
  stroke-dasharray: var(--foo);
}
#_c2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: var(--foo);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="cogs" class="animated" viewBox="-20 -20 340 340">
  <g id="g1">
  <circle id="c1" cx="150" cy="150" r="" />
  <circle id="_c1" cx="150" cy="150" r="" />
  </g>
  <g id="g2">
  <circle id="c2" cx="" cy="150" r="" />
  <circle id="_c2" cx="" cy="150" r="" />
  </g>
  <g id="g3">
  <circle id="c3" cx="150" cy="150" r=""  />
  <circle id="_c3" cx="150" cy="150" r=""  />
  </g>
 
  <use xlink:href="#g2" transform="rotate(120 150 150 )" />
  <use xlink:href="#g2" transform="rotate(240 150 150 )" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I have a difficult choice. One solution is better than another. But, unfortunately, I can not select multiple solutions at the same time. Really gear drive looks great. The teeth while rotating the gears are perfect for each other. The implementation of the code at a high level. But unfortunately another solution suits me better.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple code snipet i create to simulate the idea. All you need is

- Change SMIL style to CSS style (Don't use `animateTransform`. Use css `transform` propertive).
- Toggle `animation-play-state` when click the button

```js
const runBtn = document.getElementById('runBtn')
const pauseBtn = document.getElementById('pauseBtn')
const circle = document.getElementById('circle')

runBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!circle.classList.contains('running')) {
    circle.classList.add('running')
  }
})
pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  circle.classList.remove('running')
})
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

#circle {
  animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 200px 200px;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

#circle.running {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 400" id="rootSvg">
<g id="circle">
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" stroke-width="20" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
  <circle cx="200" cy="100" r="5" fill="yellow"/>
</g>
</svg><br>
<button id="runBtn">run</button>
<button id="pauseBtn">pause</button>
```

Comment: Try to transfer your decision to an example from my question. (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_T Sorry, i just can provide this simple example because it takes time to convert your question's example to css style. You should do it yourself

Comment: @Alexandr_T you basically need to do the same as I did for transition ... you apply the animation to each element, you adjust the origin and the different values.